# VBA Run-time error 424 object required

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on sorting a bunch of customer information based on their names into individual sheets and I was just given a new spreadsheet that I want to pull the data from and add to my previous sheets. I found some code to achieve this, but had to modify it to handle the large amount of sheet names I had. The issue comes here as every time I run the macro I am thrown

> run-time error '424': Object required

Here is the macro code I am working with

```
Sub copy_tabs()
    Dim wslist As String
    Dim sep As String
    sep = "|"
    wslist = File.ReadAllText("C:Users\MattsonC\Documents\Names.txt")
    Dim wsnames() As String
    wsnames = Split(wslist, sep, -1, vbBinaryCompare)

    Dim wsName As String
    Dim wsnamev As Variant
    For Each wsnamev In wsnames
         wsName = CStr(wsnamev)
         Call copy_tab(wsName)
    Next wsnamev
End Sub
```

When I debug it tells me the error is at

```
 wslist = File.ReadAllText("C:Users\MattsonC\Documents\Names.txt")
```

But I can't seem to figure out exactly what is wrong with that statement.

Comment: Where is `File` declared? Looks like you're trying to call a method on a nonexistent object.

Comment: The line in question looks horribly like .NET code, but you're using Visual Basic instead?

Comment: Alejandro, I had found that line from another thread as a solution to my issue with having too long of a list to reasonably fit.

Comment: That line is VB.net not VBA.  You must have gotten it from a VB.net Question.

Comment: See this link for opening/reading from .txt files in VBA: http://www.homeandlearn.org/open_a_text_file_in_vba.html